# Text comparison greater than

Tags: c#

I have text/lines like below and my requirement is check if one is greater than other. Is it really possible using c#? I you see the text is already sorted.

- 9012345EMA1234
- 9012345GHA1234
- 9012345KMA1234
- 9012345LHA1234
- 9012345LHE1234
- 9012345PHA1234

I appreciate anyone response.

Comment: greater alphabetically?

Comment: Google "C# string greater"

Comment: @FelipeP Yes. whole string.

Comment: You could in theory do a character by character sorting algorithm, but that would be dead slow and not recommended at all. What are you trying to achieve with sorting them in the order that you want?

Comment: ok, that list o strings you posted is already sorted alphabetically

Comment: Why these questions are downvoted, it is valid question !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx) link might help.

```
var something = String.Compare("9012345EMA1234", "9012345LHE1234");
```

This will give you a -1, which means that the 2nd string is the greater of the 2.

```
var something = String.Compare("9012345LHE1234", "9012345EMA1234");
```

This will give a 1....which means that the 1st string is the greater of the 2.

A 0 means they are equal.

Also try this, put all your strings in a List and then:

```
    List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "9012345EMA1234", "9012345LHE1234", "9012345KMA1234" };

    string answer = strings.Aggregate((a, b) => String.Compare(a, b) == 1 ? a : b);
```

This will get you the "greatest" string.